# why does my code continue to run forever?

Tags: python

I am learning python from MIT open courseware (i have included a link just below to the problem set) and I am unable to solve this problem for Part C without it getting into an infinite loop (i hv to ctrl + C to stop it) . Below is my code that i have written, does anyone know whats the problem?

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-0001-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-in-python-fall-2016/assignments/MIT6_0001F16_ps1.pdf

Part C, Finding the right amount to save away

```
annual_salary = float(input("Enter the starting salary:"))
current_savings = 0
num_months = 0 
r = 0.04
semi_annual_raise = 0.07 
downpayment = 250000
epsilon = 100
low = 0
high = 1
guess = (high + low)/2.0
num_guess = 0

for num_months in range (0,37):
    monthly_salary = annual_salary/12 
    current_savings += monthly_salary + current_savings*(r/12)
    if num_months % 6 == 0 and num_months > 0:
        annual_salary += annual_salary*semi_annual_raise

if current_savings < downpayment - 100:
    print("It is not possible to pay the downpayment in three years.")
else:
    for num_months in range (0,37):
        monthly_salary = monthly_salary*guess 
        current_savings += monthly_salary + current_savings*(r/12)
        if num_months % 6 == 0 and num_months > 0:
            annual_salary += annual_salary*semi_annual_raise
            monthly_salary = annual_salary/12 
        while abs(current_savings - downpayment) >= 100:
            num_guess +=1
            if current_savings < downpayment:
               low = guess 
            else:
               high = guess
        guess = (high + low)/2.0
        num_months += 1
    print ("Best savings rate:", guess)
    print ("Number of bisection searches:", num_guess)
```

Comment: Look at `while` loop in your code, it's the only place where the infinite loop is possible. There is a condition that depends on `current_savings` and `downpayment`, but these values don't change inside the loop, i.e. it will never end.